# Remove openerp title from messages

Tags: python, xml, odoo

How to remove openerp title from popup error messages / dialog boxes ?
i searched everywhere but unable to find exact phase which is need to change.

[image: error message]

please advice me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change chrome.js

line 273 and 288

```
title: "Softplanter " + _.str.capitalize(error.type),
            buttons: [
                {text: _t("Ok"), click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }}
            ]
        });
    },
    show_error: function(error) {
        if (!this.active) {
            return;
        }
        var buttons = {};
        buttons[_t("Ok")] = function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        };
        var dialog = new instance.web.Dialog(this, {
            title: "YourName " + _.str.capitalize(error.type),
```